# How can I manipulate SQL ROWNUM in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I manipulate SQL ROWNUM?

The following code was written to count the number of columns with and without COMMISSION_PCT of NULL in the EMPLOYEES table.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT T.*, ROWNUM AS RN
       FROM (
                SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM EMPLOYEES
                GROUP BY COMMISSION_PCT) T
      ) T2
```

And the result came out like this:

```
COUNT(*), RN
72,1
5,2
3,3
1,4
7,5
7,6
6,7
6,8
```

In this situation
If you do SELECT COUNT(*), the result is 8 in a single row.
What i want

```
72, 1
35, SUM (rows 2-8)
```

Same as above.

I am wondering how I can achieve the results I want.

Best Regard

Comment: Please show sample data.

Comment: Do you mean the number of **rows** with null commission percentage? There is only one `commission_pct` column in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(COMMISSION_PCT) as num_with_commission,
       COUNT(*) - COUNT(COMMISSION_PCT) as num_without_commission
FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

This happens to work because you say the missing value is `NULL`.  If it were something else, you can use a `CASE` expression with `SUM()` instead:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN COMMISSION_PCT <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as num_with_commission,
       SUM(CASE WHEN COMMISSION_PCT <> 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as num_without_commission
FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

EDIT:

If you want the results in two rows, you can unpivot the above.  Or just use two queries:

```
SELECT 'With Commission', COUNT(*)
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE COMMISSION_PCT IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Without Commission', COUNT(*) 
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE COMMISSION_PCT IS NULL;
```

This is a bit less efficient than unpivoting, but unless `EMPLOYEES` is quite large or a complex query, you probably won't notice the difference.

Comment: Then you will also need to un-pivot the output, if the OP needs the output in the arrangement he showed in his question.

Answer (score 0):

Segregate non-null from null commission percentage and then group on the result. You can do this with a `case` expression (or in many other ways) directly in the `GROUP BY` clause. Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT T.*, ROWNUM AS RN
       FROM (
                SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM hr.EMPLOYEES
                GROUP BY case when COMMISSION_PCT is not null then 0 end) T
      ) T2;
```

The expression in `GROUP BY` is 0 when commission percentage is not null, and it is null when commission percentage is null. So there will be only two groups, one for the `case` expression equal to 0 and the other for it being null.

It's not clear why you believe this has anything to do with "manipulating `ROWNUM`" - I don't see why you need it anywhere.